# Calculate Points Along a Vector Given A Step Interval

Tags: vectors

Imagine I have starting point at A and a destination at B

[image]

I have this setup as a vector so I know its length and direction etc.

What I would like to do is draw dots along this vector

[image]

But I would like to control the spacing between those dots which I call the step interval

Could anyone point me to what I would need to learn or lookup to solve the above issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$
{\bf v}(t) = {\bf A} + t ({\bf B} - {\bf A})
$$

for $t \in [0, 1]$. If you want a sequence of points just give $t$ equally spaced values. For example, if you want $N+1$ equally separated points you can create the sequence

$$
{\bf v}_i= {\bf v}(i/N) = {\bf A} + \frac{i}{N} ({\bf B} - {\bf A}) ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ i=0,1,\cdots,N
$$

Comment: Right so i is a loop to 0 to N but what is the condition to close the loop? Like when position B has been reached etc. ?

Comment: @ErsenOsman $i = 0, 1, \cdots, N$. So, for example

- python: `for i in range(0, N + 1):`
- C, java, C++: `for (i = 0; i <= N; i ++)`
- Mathematica `For[i = 0, i <= N, i += 1, ]`